# Cannot make my R shiny app to display ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to display reactive ggplot on my R shiny app, but it's not working, and I am not sure why. If someone can pinpoint why it is not working, it would be very appreciated.

Below are my code:

**1. ui**

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Sample Size Calculator for Binary     Covariates from Dog Data Based on Heish et. al (1998)"),
            helpText("This sample size Calculator is based on the paper 'A Simple Method of Sample Size Calculation for Linear and Logistic Regression' by Heish et al. (1998)",
                     "This calculator treats each covariate as a binary variable, based on the cutoff point of your choice.",
                     "The set of covariates considered in the model are those set of covariates in which their desirable cutoff levels were successfully identified by their ROC curves. ",
                     "Please select Significance Level, and  Cutoff Levels of each covariate that you would like to implement. The plot of Sample Size vs. Power will be displayed below:"),   
  selectInput("diagType", "Diagnosis Outcome of Interest:", c("Cancer", "Sepsis", "SIRS")),
  selectInput("alpha1", "Significance Level:", c("0.05", "0.01", "0.001")),
 conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'Cancer'",
                sliderInput("bin1", label = "Cut off level for TK:", min=1, max=20, value=10),
                sliderInput("bin2", label = "Cut off level for AGE:", min=3, max=12, value=6),
                sliderInput("bin3", label = "Cut off level for BW:", min=1, max=40, value=20)),
  conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'Sepsis'",
                sliderInput("bin4", label = "Cut off level for CRP:", min=1, max=45, value=22.5),
                sliderInput("bin5", label = "Cut off level for WBC:", min=13, max=25, value=12.5),
                sliderInput("bin6", label = "Cut off level for Temp:", min=103, max=106, value=103)),
  conditionalPanel( condition = "input.diagType == 'SIRS'",
                sliderInput("bin7", label = "Cut off level for CNP:", min=7, max=16, value=8),
                sliderInput("bin8", label = "Cut off level for Pulse:", min=104, max=180, value=135)),

  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
```

**2. SERVER**

```
 server <- function(input, output) {
 d  <- reactive({

   power.vec = c(0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95)

if(input$diagType == "Cancer"){
a = input$alpha1  
b1 = input$bin1
b2 = input$bin2
b3 = input$bin3
e<-calculator.cancer(a,b1,b2,b3)
}

if(input$diagType == "Sepsis"){
  a = input$alpha1  
  b4 = input$bin4
  b5 = input$bin5
  b6 = input$bin6
  e<-calculator.sepsis(a,b4,b5,b6)
} 

  if(input$diagType == "SIRS"){
   a = input$alpha1  
   b7 = input$bin7
   b8 = input$bin8
   e <-calculator.sirs(a,b7,b8)
   }
 })

 output$plot <- renderPlot({
       b <- d()
       p <- ggplot(b, aes(x = power.vec, y = e) + labs(
                                            x = "Level of Power",
                                            y = "Sample Size",
                                            title = "Plot of Sample Size versus Power") + geom_point() + geom_line())
   print(p)

      })
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Why is my ggplot not displayed? Thank you,

Comment: your ggplot syntax is wrong. You're adding `+labs` and `geom_point` INSIDE the `ggplot()` call. it should be after. You have a parenthesis in the wrong place. you need one more before the plus sign here `ggplot(b, aes(x = power.vec, y = e)>)< + `

Comment: even when I fix that it's still not working

Comment: Do you not get any sort of error? When I run this code I get an error about the "calculator.cancer" not being found. Hard to tell what the problem is if we don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: when I don't use the ggplot, but just use the ordinary plot() function to plot the graphs, it works beautifully. I don't think it's an issue with my calculator functions

Comment: the error says: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

Comment: @HDC in that case, you probably want to navigate to the logs: `/var/log/shiny-server.log` or `/var/log/shiny-server/*.log` and see what they say. Worth a shot: are you sure `ggplot2` is installed on the server?